# Escape the Trolls, or just walking through a maze

Tags: clojure

Clojure beginner, looking to improve this code I submitted for [Escape the Trolls](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/4vrb8n/weekly_25_escape_the_trolls/), a Weekly Programming challenge over in reddit. No trolls yet, just walking through a maze for now.

```
(ns ctrollmaze.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(def sample-maze
"#####################################
# #       #       #     #         # #
# # ##### # ### ##### ### ### ### # #
#       #   # #     #     # # #   # #
##### # ##### ##### ### # # # ##### #
#   # #       #     # # # # #     # #
# # ####### # # ##### ### # ##### # #
# #       # # #   #     #     #   # #
# ####### ### ### # ### ##### # ### #
#     #   # #   # #   #     # #     #
# ### ### # ### # ##### # # # #######
#   #   # # #   #   #   # # #   #   #
####### # # # ##### # ### # ### ### #
#     # #     #   # #   # #   #     #
# ### # ##### ### # ### ### ####### #
# #   #     #     #   # # #       # #
# # ##### # ### ##### # # ####### # #
# #     # # # # #     #       # #   #
# ##### # # # ### ##### ##### # #####
# #   # # #     #     # #   #       #
# # ### ### ### ##### ### # ##### # #
# #         #     #       #       # #
#X###################################")

(defrecord Maze [width
                 height
                 grid])

(defn flatten-coords
  [maze x y]
  (let [width (:width maze)]
    (+ x (* y width) y)))

(defn token-at
  [maze x y]
  (let [grid (:grid maze)]
    (nth grid (flatten-coords maze x y))))

(defn is-token?
  [maze x y given-token]
  (let [token (token-at maze x y)]
    (= given-token token)))

(defn is-wall?
  [maze x y]
  (is-token? maze x y \#))

(defn is-walkable?
  [maze x y]
  (some (partial is-token? maze x y) '(\space \X)))

(defmulti gen-maze (fn [strategy] (:strategy strategy)))

(defmethod gen-maze :static
  [strategy]
  (->Maze (:width strategy) (:height strategy) (into [] (seq sample-maze))))

(defn move-player
  [direction player]
  (case direction
    "a" (assoc player :dir \< :x (dec (:x player)))
    "d" (assoc player :dir \> :x (inc (:x player)))
    "w" (assoc player :dir \^ :y (dec (:y player)))
    "s" (assoc player :dir \v :y (inc (:y player)))
    player))

(defn gen-static-maze
  []
  (gen-maze { :strategy :static :width 37 :height 23 }))

(defn place-player
  ([maze player] (place-player maze player player))
  ([maze player' player]
   (println player' player)
   (let [{:keys [grid width height]} maze
         x' (:x player')
         y' (:y player')
         dir' (:dir player')
         x (:x player)
         y (:y player)]
     (->Maze width height (assoc grid
                                 (flatten-coords maze x y) \space
                                 (flatten-coords maze x' y') dir')))))


(defn pretty-print
  [maze]
  (let [grid (:grid maze)]
    (println (str/join grid))))

(defn is-game-finished?
  [maze]
  (->> (:grid maze)
       (some #{\X})
       (boolean)
       (not)))

(defn play-maze
  []
  (loop [player { :dir \> :x 1 :y 1 }
         maze (place-player (gen-static-maze) player)
         input-dir nil]
    (let [player' (move-player input-dir player)]
      (if (is-walkable? maze (:x player') (:y player'))
        (let [maze' (place-player maze player' player)]
          (pretty-print maze')
          (if (is-game-finished? maze')
            true
            (recur player' maze' (read-line))))
        (recur player maze (read-line))))))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (when (play-maze)
    (println "Congratulations, you won!")))
```

**Version 1.1:** No longer does the output lag behind one move.

Answer (score 1):

Looks clean enough IMO, separate functions, a record for the maze -
perhaps create one for the player too?

- When run from the terminal the `(println player' player)` is just
  noise, I'd remove it.  Also, the maze should be printed once before
  any commands are entered.
- A lot of the `let`s can be inlined as they're only used once.
- I'd perhaps pass coordinates in pairs instead of single numbers, then
  you save a parameter every time and keep those two values that belong
  together in one place.  OTOH the update code will be a little bit more
  complex.
- For `is-game-finished?` the threading macro `->>` looks like overkill,
  it's not like the expression is very complicated.
- The return value of `play-maze` doesn't really matter, does it, so
  maybe just drop the `true` and use `when` instead.

---

- Perhaps add a way to clear the screen before printing the maze, then
  at least on the terminal it's less cluttered.
- Perhaps also switch to reading single characters so you don't have to
  constantly press the Enter key.